# Making asynchronous HTTP calls from flows

Tags: corda

In Corda, how can I make an asynchronous HTTP request from within a flow? Is there an API to suspend a flow while awaiting the response to the HTTP call, or a way to provide a callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corda doesn't currently provide a mechanism for making an asynchronous HTTP request and then either suspending the flow while awaiting a response, or providing a callback that will be called when the response is received.

Instead, it is recommended that you make the HTTP request before initiating the flow, then pass in the response as an argument when instantiating the flow.

Sometimes, this isn't possible. For example, the HTTP request may be required by a response flow that is initiated automatically, or it may depend on the contents of a message received from a counterparty.

In this case, you can still support this kind of workflow as follows. Suppose you are writing a CorDapp for loan applications, which are represented as `LoanApplicationState`s. Without an HTTP call, the responder doesn't know whether to accept the loan application or not.

Instead of creating a `LoanApplicationState` directly, the flow would create an `UnacceptedLoanApplicationState`, which the responder would store on their ledger. Once the flow ends, the responder can make an HTTP call outside of the flow framework. Based on the result of the HTTP call, the responder will either kick off an approve flow that creates a transaction to transform the `UnacceptedLoanApplicationState` into an `LoanApplicationState`, or kick off a reject flow to consume the `UnacceptedLoanApplicationState` state without issuing an accepted `LoanApplicationState`.

Alternatively, you could add a status field to the `LoanApplicationState`, specifying whether the loan is approved or not. Initially, the loan state would have the field set to unapproved. Then, based on the result of the HTTP request, the responder would initiate one of two flows to update the `LoanApplicationState`, updating it with either an approved or a rejected status.

Comment: In your Loan example, how Corda client will know that there is a new UnacceptedLoanApplicationState, so that it can make http call and invoke new flow for LoanApplicationState?

Comment: You can use `CordaRPCOps.vaultTrackBy` on the server side to check when a new unaccepted loan application has been registered.

Comment: Thanks @Joel, Just one more question, async call is not possible, but sync call is possible, right? If yes, can we do something like invoke the other flow i.e accept or reject flow after receiving LoanApplication. But the doubt in this approach is, the other flow will fail as LoanApplication wouldn't have been committed yet and it should be present as input..

Comment: That's an interesting race-condition question. Can you raise it separately?

Comment: Done, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627896/corda-race-condition-invoking-some-other-flow-from-current-flow-but-input-stat

Answer (score 1):

Corda uses `quasar fibers` to make sync-like (async) calls. Fortunately quasar has support for `java's Future` and `guava's ListenableFuture`.

Based on that, you could create a Flow like this

```
@InitiatingFlow
class ListenableFutureFlow<V>(val futureFn: () -> ListenableFuture<V>,
                              override val progressTracker: ProgressTracker) : FlowLogic<V>() {

    constructor(futureFn: () -> ListenableFuture<V>) : this(futureFn, tracker())

    companion object {
        object EXECUTING_FUTURE: ProgressTracker.Step("Executing future call inside fiber")
        fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(EXECUTING_FUTURE)
    }

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): V {
        progressTracker.currentStep = EXECUTING_FUTURE
        return AsyncListenableFuture.get(futureFn())
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
val asyncResponse = subFlow(ListenableFutureFlow { myAsyncCall(param1, param2) })
```

It is not the best solution but at least works with corda's infrastructure :)

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Interesting, so this method suspends the current fibre and awakens it when the future resolves?

Comment: Should also be noted that this approach will leak threadlocal resources... e.g. DB connections.