# Corda Race Condition, Invoking some other flow from current flow, but input state is from current flow

Tags: corda

This question is raised while discussing [Making asynchronous HTTP calls from flows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700190/making-asynchronous-http-calls-from-flows)

Suppose, we are implementing a Loan Application. After a `LoanRequest` is received, Corda flow will make an HTTP call to verify the request and we want to invoke other transaction automatically according to the result of HTTP call i.e to record `ApprovedLoan` or `RejectedLoan` State.

Now problem in this scenario is, `ApprovedLoan` or `RejectedLoan` transaction will need input state as `LoanRequest`. So we can't invoke the other flow from Acceptor of `LoanRequest` flow as the input state is not committed yet and thus resulting in race condition.

Any suggestion or examples on how this can be implemented would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit the `LoanRequest` transaction to each node's storage first, before making the call in the acceptor to decide whether to approve or reject the request. You also need to use `FlowLogic.waitForLedgerCommit` to ensure you don't kick off the approval or rejection before the `LoanRequest` has been stored. Here's an example:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator(val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    /**
     * The flow logic is encapsulated within the call() method.
     */
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val session = initiateFlow(otherParty)

        val fullySignedTx: SignedTransaction = TODO("Build fully signed transaction.")

        subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx))

        session.send(fullySignedTx.id)
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val session: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        TODO("Response logic for building fully signed transaction.")

        val txId = session.receive<SecureHash>().unwrap { secureHash -> secureHash }

        waitForLedgerCommit(txId)

        val approve: Boolean = TODO("Make HTTP call to decide whether to approve or reject.")

        if (approve) {
            TODO("Response logic for building approval transaction.")
        } else {
            TODO("Response logic for building rejection transaction.")
        }
    }
}
```