# Calling external service from corda

Tags: corda

There is a bank which creates a contract which is then accepted by the lender and the borrower. After signing the contract the lender provides fund to the borrower. The bank then creates an obligation state based on the data received by calling an external service automatically.

And Now

1) In API Layer, I am calling first flow which creates one state.

2) In API layer itself, On success of first flow , I am calling the http request to external service and get the data.

3) Now I pass the http response to the the second flow for creating the other state.

Can you please let me know if there is any issue with this approach.

Requirment is I want to trigger the first flow manually, but calling external service and initiating the second flow should happen automatically

I had referred the link given below.
[Making asynchronous HTTP calls from flows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700190/making-asynchronous-http-calls-from-flows)

Comment: You already have the answer. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'll make calls to an external service during the running of flows.

The best place to get started would be looking at the CorDapp samples [here](http://www.corda.net/samples). In particular, take a look at the *Accessing External Data* section