# Placing a timeout on `receive` calls in Corda flows

Tags: corda

I have written a Corda flow that expects to receive data from multiple counterparties. If a node takes too long to send the data (e.g. because the counterparty node or the network is down), I want to timeout after waiting a certain amount of time, and continue executing the flow.

Is this possible in Corda?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a future with a timeout waiting on a VaultQuery for specific states. (btw: the future must be quasar compatible - to support being suspended)

e.g as I have described here (different context but similar approach) [Is it possible to suspend a flow such that it can be resumed with an RPC-call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447755/is-it-possible-to-suspend-a-flow-such-that-it-can-be-resumed-with-an-rpc-call/48208064#48208064)

When creating the future on the VaultQuery you can specify a timeout. Have implemented such and it works; the future waited for the arrival of the data then continued. Although I'll defer to the Corda dev team for any further comments on this approach.

Comment: That's a cool solution. I guess this only works for `send`s that put something in the vault on the other side?

Comment: Yes that's right; I was waiting on custom ContractStates. I assume you could implement a future waiting on anything from within a flow?? I Figured that waiting on a ContractState avoids more complex considerations arising from flow suspension e.g. waiting on data flow from a port if a flow has been suspended....etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3, the ability to add timeouts on `receive` or `sendAndReceive` calls isn't implemented at present.

It may be added as an extension to the platform in the future.